# Access violation reading location when accessing a dll method

Tags: c++, dll, getprocaddress

I am using the following code to access a method in the dll file and I am getting an `Access violation reading location 0x41100000` when calling the method from the dll method.

The method that I am trying to access is of the following prototype

```
 int dstoch(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);
```

This is my code

```
typedef int (*LPMyfunct)(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);
HINSTANCE hDLL = NULL;
LPMyfunct lpdstoch = NULL;

hDLL = LoadLibrary("c:\\myfile.dll");

if(hDLL!=NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Library loaded \n";
    lpdstoch = (LPMyfunct)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDLL, "dstoch");

    int res = 0;
    if(lpdstoch != NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            res = lpdstoch(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.4,6.4,7.4,8.8,9.9); //Gives the error
        }
        catch (std::exception &e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }   
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what the reasons could be ? Any chance there is an error in the dll file ?
Is there any way I could read the parameters of the dll file ? Disect it to check if I am getting the parameter types correct ? Decpendency checker shows that the method exists but I cant acertain the argument types ?

**Update:**

I am still getting the error

> First-chance exception at 0x0040356c in test.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x42080000. Unhandled exception at
>   0x0040356c in Cexperiment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0x42080000.

I also believe that this issue might not be related to a calling convention .The reason I believe is because I do not get an error message from VS2010 stating that a calling convention may be a cause.I got that message when i tried using some other dll. So if calling convention or parameters are not an issue (you get the same calling convention message incase the parameters are different) then it might be something else. Any suggestions on what I could try ?

Comment: In your other question, you said it takes 9 floats. Here you are passing 9 non-floats.

Comment: Yes. I thought the coversion would be implicit. I have tried passing floats and I get the same answer

Comment: Don't worry, the ints in place of floats is fine.

Comment: Conversion will be implicit if the signature is right. You don't show what `LPMyfunct` is here, nor what the actual prototype of dstoch is. The calling convention double-check is also relevant.

Comment: sorry just updated the post

Answer (score 2):

You need to check calling convention of the dll function and declare `LPMyfunct` type accordingly. Possible values for calling conventions are: `stdcall`, `cdecl`, `pascal`.

Comment: @igor are you suggesting that `typedef int (*LPMyfunct)(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);` could possibly be `typedef int (_stdcall *LPMyfunct)(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);` or of the types you mentioned ?

Comment: @MistyD, Yes, it depends on what it is in the DLL.

Comment: I am currently trying each of those. On a side note is there a difference between `__stdcall` or `_stdcall` ?

Comment: I am not aware of "single underscore" stdcall. Unless it is defined somewhere to mean `__stdcall`.

Comment: Yeah am reading the details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58%28v=vs.71%29.aspx